# call retrieve function in paulirish/infinite-scroll

Tags: jquery

I want to manually trigger the next page load in paulirish/infinite-scroll. I found a function called

```
retrieve: function infscr_retrieve(pageNum) {
}
```

I tried to call it directly using something like this.

```
    var contentScroll = $('#content');
    contentScroll.infinitescroll({
       //bla...........
    });

contentScroll.infinitescroll.retrieve(2);
```

error retrieve is not a function. 
Anyone know how I could go about calling this method.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#your-selector').infinitescroll('retrieve',5)
```

The optional 5 is for the page number. Took a bit of digging around the net to find this one. 
hope it helps someone out.